# How to fill input element value with function, but still be able to assign the value manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a `select` element that passes its value into `input` element with the `fillInput()` function. The code looks like this:

```
let fillInput = ()=>{

    let select = document.getElementById('type').value
    let changeInput=document.getElementById('InputField').value
    changeInput=select

}

const Edit = props => { 
   if (props.selectedObj){
    return (             
        <div>
        {fillInput()}
            <div>
                <div>
                  <select
                      id='type'
                      value={props.selectedObj.type}
                      onChange={props.onChange}
                  >
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    id='InputField'
                    value={props.selectedObj.InputValue}
                    onChange={props.onChange}
                  >
                  </input>
                </div> 
            </div>   
        </div>   
    )}
};
```

The function works fine, but when i try to fill the `input` value manually, it still shows the value passed in by the `fillinput()` function. I am new to JS but i think that some specific event listener would help? Any suggestions?

Also, the result of the function is shown visually but does not seem to really assign the value to the `selectedObj`. The `Edit` const is used to create an object that is saved into database, but the values assigned by `fillInput()` function is not passed into the database (it worked fine when i tried it manually and the `fillInput()` function was not involved).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instend of

```
 value={props.selectedObj.InputValue}
```

write

```
defaultValue={props.selectedObj.InputValue}
```

for more details 
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: Thank you, that solved the first problem. I guess the second problem is caused somewhere else in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
    onChange={props.onChange}
```

because it is causing to recall your function which replaces value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it but then i cannot write into the field manually at all.